# Using Linux virtual mouse driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mouse, mouseevent, linux-device-driver

I am trying to implement a *virtual mouse driver* according to the **Essential Linux device Drivers** book. There is a *user space* application, which generates coordinates as well as a kernel module.

See: [Virtual mouse driver and userspace application code](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/EssentialLinuxDeviceDrivers/final/ch07lev1sec1.html) and also a [step by step](http://www.matveev.se/linux/vms.htm) on how to use this driver.

1.) I compile the code of the *user space* application and driver.

2.) Next i checked `dmesg` output and have,

> **input: Unspecified device as /class/input/input32**
>   **Virtual Mouse Driver Initialized**

3.) The *sysfs* node was created properly during initialization (found in `/sys/devices/platform/vms/coordinates`)

4.) I know that the virtual mouse driver (**input32** ) is linked to **event5** by checking the following:

> **$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices**
>   I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
>   N: Name=""
>   P: Phys=
>   S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input32
>   U: Uniq=
>   H: Handlers=event5
>   B: EV=5
>   B: REL=3

5.) Next i attach a *GPM* server to the event interface: `gpm -m /dev/input/event5 -t evdev`

6.) Run the *user space* application to generate random coordinates for virtual mouse and observe generated coordinates using `od -x /dev/input/event5`.

And nothing happens. Why? 
Also [here](http://www.matveev.se/linux/vms.htm) author mentioned that `gdm` should be stopped, using **/etc/init.d/gdm stop**, but i get *"no such service"* when stopping `gdm`.

**Here is my complete script for building and runing virtual mouse:**

```
make -C /usr/src/kernel/2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686/ SUBDIRS=$PWD modules
gcc -o app_userspace app_userspace.c
insmod app.ko
gpm -m /dev/input-event5 -t evdev
./app_userspace
```

**Makefile:**

```
obj-m+=app.o
```

Kernel version: **2.6.35.6**

---

As i said before i can recieve the result through od, but i received it through your program
**echo 9 19 > /sys/devices/platform/virmouse/vmevent**

gives:

**time 1368284298.207654    type 2  code 0  value 9**

**time 1368284298.207657    type 2  code 1  value 19**

**time 1368284298.207662    type 0  code 0  value 0**

### So now the question is: what is wrong with X11? I would like to stress, that i tried this code under two different distributions Ubuntu 11.04 and Fedora 14.

---

Maybe this will help: in Xorg.0.log i see the following:

[ 21.022] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)

[ 272.987] (II) config/udev: Adding input device (/dev/input/event5)

[ 272.987] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)

[ 666.521] (II) config/udev: Adding input device (/dev/input/event5)

[ 666.521] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)

Comment: I use ubuntu distro not a custom kernel, is it ok for this example?

Comment: *So now the question is: what is wrong with X11?*  This question is not for [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) then.

Comment: maybe the cause lies in virtual machine? (i use virtualbox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent a huge amount of time, resolving this issue, and i would like to help other people, who run in this problem. I think some outer **X11** features interfered my module work. After **disabling GDM** it now works fine (runlevel 3). Working code you can find here http://fred-zone.blogspot.ru/2010/01/mouse-linux-kernel-driver.html working distro ubuntu 11.04 (gdm disabled)

Comment: I disabled lightdm in Xubuntu 12.04 (it replaced gdm) and am still having the same issue. Really don't know what to make of this.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the below lines of code in the input device driver

```
set_bit(EV_REL, vms_input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(REL_X, vms_input_dev->relbit);
set_bit(REL_Y, vms_input_dev->relbit);
```

with

```
vms_input_dev->name = "Virtual Mouse";
vms_input_dev->phys = "vmd/input0"; // "vmd" is the driver's name
vms_input_dev->id.bustype = BUS_VIRTUAL;
vms_input_dev->id.vendor  = 0x0000;
vms_input_dev->id.product = 0x0000;
vms_input_dev->id.version = 0x0000;

vms_input_dev->evbit[0] = BIT_MASK(EV_KEY) | BIT_MASK(EV_REL);
vms_input_dev->keybit[BIT_WORD(BTN_MOUSE)] = BIT_MASK(BTN_LEFT) | BIT_MASK(BTN_RIGHT) | BIT_MASK(BTN_MIDDLE);
vms_input_dev->relbit[0] = BIT_MASK(REL_X) | BIT_MASK(REL_Y);
vms_input_dev->keybit[BIT_WORD(BTN_MOUSE)] |= BIT_MASK(BTN_SIDE) | BIT_MASK(BTN_EXTRA);
vms_input_dev->relbit[0] |= BIT_MASK(REL_WHEEL);
```

It worked for me on ubuntu 12.04