# How can i create new virtual mouse device on my android device?

Tags: android, linux, input, linux-kernel, mouse

I know, I can listen input devices from `/dev/input/eventx` on **Android/Linux**. If you are **superuser**, you can also send events to the device through that.

I would like to send *mouse events* to my *Android device* as **superuser**. However, in order to do this, a mouse must be connected to the device via USB or bluetooth connection. Without it, I get error as `Could not open /dev/input/event8, No such device` when execute this command on adb `sendevent /dev/input/event8 xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx`. In this case, the node was attempted to be created using the `mknod /dev/input/event8 c 13 71` command.

The problem is solved when I connect a bluetooth or USB mouse to the device. The device is created automatically under `/sys/devices/platform/tegra_uart.2/tty/ttyHS2/hci0` named *hci0:11* also create input event `/dev/input/event7 (major 13 minor 71)`. After that I can send events to that node and control Android mouse cursor. But I want to do this without connecting a mouse to the device.

**Could anyone suggest how can I create a mouse input device (like when a mouse is connected) on my android device *virtually*?**

Comment: Yes, such as touchscreen but without real hardware device. I mean, virtual mouse device.

Comment: @ErdemUYSAL See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/input/input.txt and also the code under drivers/input/mouse/.

Comment: @PeterL. Thank you for your advice. But my problem is still not resolved. Because there is gpm command in Linux, but there isn't in Android :S

Comment: do you find the solution ? I need that too

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue at the moment. By any chance, have you found a solution already?

Comment: So are you trying to inject touch events? Have you read this: http://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/

Comment: you don't have to inject on a mouse device. You can draw your own mouse cursor, and inject touch event when user clicks, it's a little complicated when handling drag or fling, but should work:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what i see you should create your own virtual device with your own driver , Fortunately there is an easy way to do so using **[uinput](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/misc/uinput.c)**

There is an easy guide for getting started **[here](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput)** , and this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482260/using-linux-virtual-mouse-driver)** can be a good guide to write your own virtual driver.

I thought this can only be done if you have access to kernel , and create your own ( i dont think modifying user rom is a good solution ) , but after reading **[this](http://afantao.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-use-uinput-device-model.html)** , it is clear that Uinput can run in user mode.

**Note :**

I agree with recommendition to use touch events ; as this solution is more common and makes sense , check second suggestion is this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420959/new-to-kernel-development-virtual-input-driver-in-kernel)**

Comment: Great answer. I want to add that the device will disappear once the program terminates. I've been able to create an input device and send input events to the /dev/input/event* file.

Comment: @LeonvanNoord thanks , glad i could help , but can you please be more clear about device disappear thing ? just to help whoever seek this answer in future.

Comment: If the program described in part 1 of the [guide](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) finishes running, the device disappears. It's not present anymore in /proc/bus/input/devices and the corresponding /dev/input/event* also disappears.